# I dont undertand why the console is showing me undefined

Tags: javascript, console, undefined

I am new to coding and cannot figure out the following code. If anyone can give me a hand I will deeply aprreciate!!

```js
function a() {
  function b() {
    console.log(x);
  }
  var x = 2;
  b();
}
var x = 1;
a();
```

When I run this code it makes perfect sense that the console is `2`. Super!

But when I run this code:

```js
function a() {
  b();

  function b() {
    console.log(x);
  }
  var x = 2;
}
var x = 1;
a();
```

When this code runs, I would have thought that the console answer would be `2` as well! but I get `undefined` as the answer. At least I would have thought that `1` could be the answer in case it was not 2, but never ever: `undefined`.

Can anybody please give me a hand?

Many thanks!

Comment: Statements are executed in order. You're calling `b()` before you initialize the variable.

Comment: You don't get `1` because that variable is in a different scope.

Comment: I know there are duplicates of this question, I just can't find them now.

Comment: Variable hoising is the reason that the variable is local to the function, even though the declaration is after the call.

Comment: Code is run from top to bottom... of course `x` is going to be undefined if you reference it before you assign it anything.

Answer (score 4):

`var` declarations are hoisted.

That means that these declarations are moved to the top of the current scope (function) at compile time (before the code runs).

Hoisting **does** move the variable *declaration*, but **does not** move the variable *assignment*.

Thus, this code:

```js
doSomething();
var variable = value; //Declaration with assignment
```

is transformed to:

```js
var variable; //Declaration
doSomething();
variable = value; //Assignment
```

So, your code is identical to the following:

```js
function a() {
  var x; //x is now undefined
  
  //Function declarations are hoisted as well:
  function b() {
    console.log(x);
  }
  
  b(); //x is still undefined now...

  x = 2; //x is now 2, but your console.log has already run.
}
var x = 1; //This line doesn't affect your code, as the x you log is in different scope, and the internal x shadows this one.
a();
```

Answer (score 0):

so x is undefined in your second example because of the fact that you initialized x (i.e. var x = 2) **after** you called function b (i.e. b()). That means the program does not know what x is yet when you called function b so when you do call b() you are trying to print something you have not yet defined to the program.

The first example works because x is defined before the function call to b

Comment: So the following code: